# Accessing variables and methods across threads

Tags: java

I am using java to create an interface to connect to a database. Each time I want to make a call to the database I need to create new connections to the database, which would make calling the database say 10 times slow.

To avoid having to create new connections each time I want to call the database I have a java thread running that holds all of the connection information.

To write/read from the database I want to create a thread that uses the connection information stored in the thread that's already running, use it to execute specified read/write functions, and then exit.

However I am having trouble accessing this information from the thread which is already running. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a thread running to keep your connection open, just store it somewhere and execute queries as soon as you need it.. should it work?

In any case if you really want a thread you should care about having a synchronized collection (check `Collections.asSynchronizedList`) that can be accessed and managed from your thread and others too.

To overcome visibility problems just declare it as a `static final` variable, so you won't have any problems in accessing it from outside the thread you declared it into.

Another easy solution (since connection seems to be not thread-safe) is not to use a thread but use just a monitor: you can easily manage a `wait()`/`notify()` mechanism for which a thread that wants to execute a query checks if connection is "free". if it is occupies the monitor and do whatever it wants before notifying all waiting threads.

Comment: No mutable statics! And what do you think you are going to do once you have a `synchronizedList`? My guess is external synchronisation or, more likely, race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible idea, because java.sql.Connection is not thread-safe.

A better idea would be to use a connection pool.  Let each thread check out a connection, use it, and put it back.

Comment: I'm not using java.sql.Connection or any other java sql implementations

Comment: You wrote your own using the database API?  Which database?  If you made it thread safe, I'll withdraw my comment.  If you didn't even think about it or don't know what that means, my comment still stands.

Comment: I'm working on my own API for a small text file database system I'm also working on.

I accounted for thread safety.

It's a for fun project.

Comment: Are you sure you accounted for thread-safety. It is decidedly non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

best way is not to re-invent the wheel. there are good open spource implementations of the connection pooling and i suggest you use them.

if you are already running in a container then use DataSource. look into c3p0 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) and commons-dbcp (http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing this?  There are frameworks, like Spring or equivalent, which will manage your connections for you.  Don't reinvent the wheel man....

Comment: Re-invent the wheel?  Mr. King doesn't even want to use JDBC to access a database.

Comment: @duffymo  ;) some people like to do it for learnings sake...i guess i feel there is enough to be confused about not doing things like this...ill take the help i can get, wrt frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a **generic object pool** instead of building your own solution and suggest to check [Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) from Apache Commons (this is an API for generic Object pooling, this isn't DBCP).